# Angular: how to language from path in APP_INITIALIZER?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

So, we are using APP_INITIALIZER to load some settings (via http) on app load.... but, the problem is that those settings depends on the language path

so
mydomain.com/en
gets different settings than
mydomain.com/it

how can we (safely) determine the language from the app path?

this is the logic we have now

site.service.ts:

```
load(): Promise<SiteConfiguration> {
  const promise = this.getSiteSettings().toPromise();

  promise.then(config => {
    this.config = config;
     return config;
  }
  return promise;
}

getSiteSettings(): Observable<any> {
  // language logic supposed to be
  const langId = 'en';

  return this.http.get(`${environment.apiPath}/${langId}.siteconfiguration.json`)
  .map(res)
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
}
```

assuming the language is always be the first param in the path

Comment: Can't you use window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]? But if you use angular universal, you'll need to pass real the url from server to the initializer, or even just the language

Comment: we do use universal.... so how would I pass the language value from express server to the initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using express/nodejs in your backend

1. On the backend server, identify the language id from your express request

   ```
   let languageId = req.path.split('/')[1];
   ```
2. On the backend server, provide the language URL

   ```
   renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
       // Our index.html
       document: template,
       url: url,
       extraProviders: [
         provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
         {
           provide: 'languageId',
           useValue: languageId
         }
       ]
   ```
3. Modify your initializer service to inject the language

   ```
   constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private 
   platformId: Object, @Optional() @Inject('languageId') protected languageId: string)    
   {
   }
   ```
4. Use the injected value

   ```
     getSiteSettings(): Observable<any> {

       const langId = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)? window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] : this.languageId;
       return this.http.get(`${environment.apiPath}/${langId}.siteconfiguration.json`)
       .map(res)
       .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
     }
   ```